# ask user enter name with Javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I have code to ask the user to enter their name and display it in a `<p>` element

```js
function my() {
  var x = document.getElementById("tt").textContent;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<h1> Whats your name ? </h1>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="tt" placeholder="Enter Name : ">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
</form>
<button onclick="my">Submit now</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

i expect the output will be print name of user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `value` property rather than the `textContext` property. `input`  type fields use `value` and have no `textContent`.

Additionally, your `onclick` is incorrectly defined. I recommend using `javascript:myFunction()` format, when executing a function in this manner. See below:

```js
function my() {
  var x = document.getElementById("tt").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<h1> Whats your name ? </h1>

  <input type="text" id="tt" placeholder="Enter Name : ">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>

<button onclick="javascript:my()">Submit now</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

You'll notice I  also removed  the `form` node. If you don't `preventDefault` on a `form` it will refresh the page upon submit.

It's fine for this kind of thing to just not use a `form` tag. But if you wanted to keep it, you'll want to select it and `preventDefault` behavior like this:

```
var myForm = document.querySelector('form');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro , i'm very happy for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

2 items:

1. An `input` element doesn't have `textContent`, it has a `value`.
2. When delcaring an `onclick` handler, include the parenthesis `()` to indicate it's a function call.

```js
function my() {
  var x = document.getElementById("tt").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<h1> Whats your name ? </h1>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="tt" placeholder="Enter Name : ">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
</form>
<button onclick="my()">Submit now</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks you bro :) , i have test your code and its work ! , i never forget your favor

Answer (score 1):

You are having some syntax errors in code. Missing `()`, properties of input context.

```js
function display(){
  console.log('here')
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =document.getElementById("tt").value;  
 }
```

```html
<h1> Whats your name ? </h1>
<form  name = "myForm">
    <input type="text" name = "name" id="tt" placeholder="Enter Name : ">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    

</form>
<input type="submit"  onclick="display()">
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
</body>
```

[To learn about syntax and javascript.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: thanks bro for your help , i have test your code and its work !

Answer (score 0):

You missed the round brackets:
`<button onclick="my()">Submit now</button>`

Comment: thanks you bro ,i have test a code and its work ! , thanks for your help